# C is exit behaving like return?

Tags: c, return, program-entry-point, exit

In c code , return and exit from main behaving same ?

```
int main (int argc , char* argv[])
{
    exit(2);
}
```

and

```
int main (int argc , char* argv[])
{
    return 2;
}
```

when both of code called from another c , both of them will return 2 ?

Comment: Reading about [`exit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) and [`main()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) in C would probably be helpful (and bookmark that site).

Answer (score 2):

In case of the `main()` function, calling `exit()` or using `return` statement in the end have same output observable from the host environment, they will both be returning the execution control to the environment.

However, in case of any user-defined function:

- using `return` statement will just return the control to the caller function
- calling `exit()` will return the control to the host environment, after the following

  - Call all functions registered by the `atexit` function
  - All open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, all open streams are
    closed, and all files created by the `tmpfile` function are removed.

Comment: There are subtle differences in `main()` between `return n;` and `exit(n);` under some unusual but not impossible circumstances.  The one that's usually quoted is that if you use `setbuf()` or `setvbuf()` on an open file that is not closed before the `return` or `exit()` is executed, and if you supply an array that's local to main as the buffer, then the buffer goes out of scope leading to undefined behaviour as the file is closed if you use `return` whereas it stays defined if you call `exit()`.  However, that is seldom a problem in real programs.

Answer (score 0):

`main` should behave as if it had been called inside of `exit()` (`exit(main(argc,argv))`),
so a `return` from main should be basically equivalent to `exit(retval)`, except after returning
from `main`, references to main's locals become invalid, whereas they remain  valid if you call `exit`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int *addr;
void print_thru_ptr(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", *addr);
}
int main (int argc , char* argv[])
{
    int local=42;
    addr=&local;
    atexit(print_thru_ptr);
    if(1){
        exit(2); //will print 42
    }else{
        return 2; //would be undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `exit(main(argc, argv, envp));` :D  And, indeed, on a Mac, there is even a fourth argument to `main()`.